# How to display menu item with icon and text in AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, menuitem, android-toolbar, appcompatactivity

I tried different combinations in xml file:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_create_alarm"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/menu_create_alarm"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

or

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_create_alarm"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/menu_create_alarm"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
</menu>
```

or

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_create_alarm"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/menu_create_alarm"
        app:showAsAction="withText" />
</menu>
```

or

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_create_alarm"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/menu_create_alarm"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
</menu>
```

I tried to set it programmaticly

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
        MenuItem item = menu.add(R.string.menu_create_alarm);
        item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT|MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_action_accept);
        item.setOnMenuItemClickListener(
            new OnMenuItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item){
                    saveAlarm();
                    return true;
                }
            }
        );


//      inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_create_alarm, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    }
```

or

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_create_alarm"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/menu_create_alarm"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
</menu>
```

However, Only Icon appears. And there is planty of room, cause I did not set toolbar title. Removing menues and replasing them with button inside toolbar is not sutable.
How to display text?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14932216/action-bar-sub-menu-item-with-text-and-image-not-working-properly

Comment: @vab yo make link to answers, with solution already listed and not working

Comment: Icon + text or only text??

Comment: @XxGoliathusxX icon+ text.

Comment: do you have one menu item? or severall

Comment: @Elltz only one, which is listed in examples above

Comment: May be this could help clear the picture http://stackoverflow.com/a/12225863/2819262

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use following code for establishing your purpose. No need to make it programmatic. You can trick in menu.xml file.

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<item
    android:id="@+id/overflowMenu"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_more_vert_white_24dp"
    android:title=""
    app:showAsAction="always">

    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/menuWithIconText"
            android:icon="@drawable/chosen_icon"
            android:title="@string/menu_item_title"
            />
    </menu>
</item>
```

In above code, we've used `menu` inside of `item`. In inside menu, we've defined our overflow menu which we want with icon. Just remember to use `app:showAsAction="always"` in outside `item` tag.

Comment: I don't have such a drawable in my project and when i add it it says that it's not found.

Comment: @SubqueryCrunch drawable is folder where you save icons. Basically in drawable folder you keep all your assets. Please check your assets folder and select it in android:icon attribute.

Answer (score 32):

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
//        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_patient_home_screen, menu);


        menu.add(0, 1, 1, menuIconWithText(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.user_2), getResources().getString(R.string.action_profile)));
        menu.add(0, 2, 2, menuIconWithText(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.add_user), getResources().getString(R.string.action_add_user)));
        menu.add(0, 3, 3, menuIconWithText(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.switch_profile), getResources().getString(R.string.action_switch_profile)));
        menu.add(0, 4, 4, menuIconWithText(getResources().getDrawable(R.mipmap.logout), getResources().getString(R.string.action_sign_out)));
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case 1:
                Toast.makeText(PatientHomeScreen.this, "Profile is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case 2:
                Toast.makeText(PatientHomeScreen.this, "Add New User is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case 3:
                Toast.makeText(PatientHomeScreen.this, "Switch Profile is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case 4:
                Toast.makeText(PatientHomeScreen.this, "Sign Out is Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private CharSequence menuIconWithText(Drawable r, String title) {

        r.setBounds(0, 0, r.getIntrinsicWidth(), r.getIntrinsicHeight());
        SpannableString sb = new SpannableString("    " + title);
        ImageSpan imageSpan = new ImageSpan(r, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        sb.setSpan(imageSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        return sb;
    }
```

[image: Screen shot of emulator]

Hope this will help you

Comment: Above solution works good, If you are working in Fragment you need to change only one thing, change onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) with onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater).

and add setHasOptionsMenu(true) in onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) or View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater....)

Comment: How can I do this with XML only?

Answer (score 26):

You need to add `tools:context="your class"` to menu tag

**menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   tools:context=".activities.BaseActivity">


   <item
       android:id="@+id/action_notification1"
       android:icon="@drawable/three"
       android:title="action_notification"
       app:showAsAction="always">
       <menu>
           <item
               android:id="@+id/profile"
               android:icon="@drawable/profile"
               android:orderInCategory="100"
               android:title="PROFILE" />

           <item
               android:id="@+id/c"
               android:icon="@drawable/correct_tick"
               android:orderInCategory="100"
               android:title="COMPLETED TRIPS" />

           <item
               android:id="@+id/app"
               android:icon="@drawable/report_issue"
               android:orderInCategory="100"
               android:title="REPORT ISSUES" />
           <item
               android:id="@+id/r"
               android:icon="@drawable/correct_tick"
               android:orderInCategory="100"
               android:title="REACHED CENTER" />


           <item
               android:id="@+id/pdf"
               android:icon="@drawable/pdf_image"
               android:orderInCategory="100"
               android:title="BAG INFO" />
           <item
               android:id="@+id/l"
               android:icon="@drawable/logout"
               android:orderInCategory="100"
               android:title="LOGOUT" />
       </menu>
   </item>


</menu>
```

**Override `onCreateOptionsMenu()` Method**

```
@Override 
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu); 
    menu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(3).setVisible(false);
    menu.getItem(0).getSubMenu().getItem(4).setVisible(true);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

You should write `tool:context` to menu tag then run you will get icons before your text.

Answer (score 26):

Adding to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35499253) from dev_ry, there is a much smoother way without using reflection by just casting and suppressing the restricted API warning:

```
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder;

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (menu instanceof MenuBuilder) {
        ((MenuBuilder) menu).setOptionalIconsVisible(true);
    }
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Simple but powerful solution.

Comment: saved my day bro :-)

Answer (score 13):

```
protected boolean onPrepareOptionsPanel(View view, Menu menu) {
    if (menu != null) {
        if (menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder")) {
            try {
                Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                        "setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(menu, true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                        "onMenuOpened...unable to set icons for overflow menu",
                        e);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsPanel(view, menu);
}
```

Comment: When my class extended Activity, this worked form me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22288914/555762.
But when i changed my class to extend AppCompatActivity, previous solution stoped working and this answer saved my day =)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Any change we need to make in proguard?

Comment: @Atul I have not tested it for proguard but dont think that progurad need some changes because of this.

Comment: Tried everything else to get both the icon and text to display in the drop-down menu. This worked which also gave an error which was resolved by adding @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi") before the method as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41150995/appcompatactivity-oncreate-can-only-be-called-from-within-the-same-library-group

Answer (score 10):

xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_create_alarm"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_accept"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/menu_create_alarm"
        android:showAsAction="always|withText"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText" />
</menu>
```

java:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.menu_frg_safetybox, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Comment: there is still no text, only icon

Comment: Android decides for itself at the end of the day if it can fit or not.

Comment: how to call, new inflator in fragment? If i do @Override
 public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater){
//  inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_create_level, menu);
  new MenuInflater(getActivity()).inflate(R.menu.menu_create_level, menu);

  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

 }, I still have only icon

Comment: As i said. if the OS decides that the text and icon are to large for the device, it will only put the icon. You would have to try a larger device.

Comment: but how is this diff from mine lol.. life on stackoverflow  :)

Answer (score 6):

**'always|withText'** will work if there is sufficient room, otherwise it will place only the icon.You an see that by rotating phone to landscape mode..

```
       <item
        android:id="@+id/action_create_alarm"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:title="Save"
        app:showAsAction="always|withText"
        />
```

Comment: that is correct. If I turn the device into landscape mode the text show up. Nevertheless I want to text is being displaying always. Although my Title in toolbar is very short ("Activity") text doesn't appear.

Answer (score 3):

try these two together

```
app:showAsAction="always|withText"
android:showAsAction="always|withText"
```

Comment: there is still no text, only icon

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: where is the link Sir @JohanShogun

Comment: This is the correct answer I don't know why it doesn't have more upvotes

Answer (score 2):

MyActivity.java:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        View view = menu.findItem(R.id.whats_this).getActionView();
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // do something
            }
        });
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

my_menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/item"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/my_layout"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/whats_this"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

my_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="@string/whats_this"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/question"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is not useful at all, the question is how to display an icon next to the item when the menu unfolds