# Not able to change menu item color for light and dark theme

Tags: android, themes, menuitem, android-styles, android-attributes

I am trying to implement a light and dark theme for my app by following [This blog](http://www.hidroh.com/2015/02/25/support-multiple-themes-android-app-part-2/#fn:danlew)

But in case of changing the menu items according to the theme, by following the above no menu icon is displayed only its string
This is my **attrs.xml** code-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<attr name="icon_favourite" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

This is my **Light Theme Style**

`<item name="icon_favourite">@drawable/ic_liked_toolbar</item>`

This is my **Dark Theme Style**

`<item name="icon_favourite">@drawable/ic_liked_toolbar_white</item>`

This is my **menuitem** -

```
<item xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/favourites"
    android:icon="?attrs/icon_favourite"
    android:title="@string/action_favourites" />
```

After applying all these my menu item's icon is not visible and only its string is visible

Answer (score -1):

In the activity use method :

```
setTheme(Theme);
```

before calling

```
setContentView();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually even without switching the theme through setTheme, the menu items are shown as strings only.

Comment: Try this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969172/how-to-display-menu-item-with-icon-and-text-in-appcompatactivity

Comment: I got my code working. I forgot to make changes in styles.xml(v-23) while running it on marshmallow