# Android ActionBar: Text is not showing along with icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have added this item to the ActionBar:

[image: Action bar with star]

and I have set this showAsAction value:

[image: showAsAction settings]

**The doubt**: I expected the text was also shown since the "withText" option is enabled..

Comment: Instead of actionbar use new official toolbar. [Sample Code](https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-app-toolbar)

Comment: you set it to Never then how will it show it will go to Overflow .

Comment: showAsAction should not be never

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how-to-display-menu-item-with-icon-and-text-in-appcompatactivity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32969172/how-to-display-menu-item-with-icon-and-text-in-appcompatactivity)

Answer (score 0):

`android:showAsAction="always|withText"` will work if there is enough space / room. Test it with landscape mode.

```
<item android:id="@id/item"
    android:title="text"
    android:icon="@drawable/drawable"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText" />
```